# Have an array in a SQL field. How to display it systematically?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have a field in a data feed coming in with some values separated by commas.  For one record, the values are:

```
A06,C05,C06,C15,C18,C19,C21,C22,E05,E22,G11,J02,J07,L04,L07,M01,M05,N03,N07,N10,N11,N12,N18,N19,N20,N24,O02,O03,O04,O06,O09,O14,O15,O16,O20,O21,O31,Q01,Q04,Q08,R07,S08,T08,T12,T23,T32,U01,U03,U04,U06,U13,W09,W11,W16,W19,W30,W45,X02,X03,X12,Z07
```

I have a separate table with some descriptions as to what each code means.  When I query the main table and get this field name as a value, I can use explode to get it into an array and use a foreach loop to output each value.

The problem is, I want to display the description stored in another table.  What's the proper way of iterating through this to display these values in a list?

As an example, C21 means "Gated Community."

Comment: Why don't u consider accepting few of your past questions if you find them useful ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)** function for that.

Example you have record like this

```
Orders Table
------------------------------------
OrderID     |     attachedCompanyIDs
------------------------------------
   1                     1,2,3               -- comma separated values
   2                     2,4
```

and

```
Company Table
--------------------------------------
CompanyID      |        name
--------------------------------------
    1                 Company 1
    2                 Another Company
    3                 StackOverflow
    4                 Nothing
```

Using the function

```
SELECT name 
FROM orders, company
WHERE orderID = 1 AND FIND_IN_SET(companyID, attachedCompanyIDs)
```

will result

```
name
---------------
Company 1
Another Company
StackOverflow
```

Comment: I believe the OP also intended to match the split records to another table. I feel your answer doesn't clearly show this.

Answer (score 2):

As you have tagged codeigniter you could use the built in `Active Record's` method `$this->db->where_in();` to get the description. For example consider the code below

```
$codes = array('A06', 'C05', 'C06');
$this->db->where_in('description', $codes);
// Produces: WHERE codes IN ('A06', 'C05', 'C06')
```

For more information about `Active Records` of `Codeigniter` refer [Active Record Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select)

For more information on how `mysql` `WHERE IN` works refer [Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Just for follow the books, the best way of doing this in SQL language is to use the relationship.

For understand this I recommend you read this simple paper http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships/
and maybe this http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30875&seqNum=5 for SELECT the data, or search for yourself on the web, and I recommend you to try yourself the examples. SQL Relationship Is good and necessary for security and many others reasons.